# Transfering text from textarea to lis

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to make simple to do list, i managed to make it work only on one line of h3. Now i want to make it to work on multiple lines but i don't really know how to do it. I tried using while loop but it didn't work.

html

```
 <div class="nums">
            <textarea class= "in" name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
            <button class="btn"><h2>Add</h2></button>
            <div class="hs">
                <ul>
                    <li><h3></h3></li>
                    <li><h3></h3></li>
                    <li><h3></h3></li>
                </ul>                   
                </div> 
            </div>
```

JS

```
var textin = document.querySelector('textarea');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var out = document.querySelector('h3');
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    out.textContent = textin.value;     
});
out.addEventListener("click",function(){
    out.textContent = "";
});
```

Comment: _"I tried using while loop but it didn't work."_ - There's no loop in your example hence there's some important information missing. Please provide a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: I deleted it because it would freeze page. It was bad implementation of loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your code, it is easier to append an < li > tag when you click on the button. Here have an example:
Don't forget to identify the ul

```
----
<ul id="list"></ul>
---

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var textin = document.querySelector('textarea');
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textin.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);    
});
```

Comment: No problem, you got it almost figured out. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
  h3.className = "close";
  li.appendChild(h3);
  h3.appendChild(t);
    if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
  var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
  var i;
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="nums">
  <textarea class= "in" name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" id="myInput"></textarea>
  <button class="btn"><h2>Add</h2></button>
  <div class="hs">
      <ul id="myUL">
      </ul>                   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here, my friend

```js
var textin = document.querySelector('textarea');
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var todolist = document.querySelector('#todo');

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var input = textin.value;     
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    var h3Content = document.createTextNode(input);
    h3.appendChild(h3Content);
    li.appendChild(h3);
    todolist.appendChild(li);
    textin.value = '';
});
```

```html
<div class="nums">
            <textarea class= "in" name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
            <button class="btn"><h2>Add</h2></button>
            <div class="hs">
                <ul id="todo">

                </ul>                   
                </div> 
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a little exercise I put this little fiddle together (as an alternative solution):

```js
var qs=function(s){return document.querySelector(s)}; // shortcut function ...
var ul=qs('.hs ul'), txta=qs('.in');

qs('.btn').onclick=
 function(){ul.innerHTML
   +='<li><h3>'
   +txta.value.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
   +'</h3></li>';
   txta.value=""}
```

```html
<div class="nums">
 <textarea class= "in" name="Text1" 
  cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
 <button class="btn">Add</button>
 <div class="hs">
  <ul></ul>                   
 </div> 
</div>
```

Using `.innerHTML` is no longer regarded as a "no-go". And it turns out that in many cases it can simplify matters, compared to working with `.createElement` and `.appendChild` calls.